# (kind of) rotating and slicing elements of a container in C++

Tags: c++, rotation, spline, splice

I have a `std::vector` that holds a `Point struct` (x,y,z and some other non-pointer types).

These points are control points for drawing a bspline curve. I'm not having trouble drawing the curve, but complications arise when I have to close the curve, which involves adding control points (alredy existing inside the container) in certain order.

For example, if I have 5 control points

```
A B C D E
```

I would have to get 5 sequences like this:

```
A B C D  //curve is drawn from B to C
B C D E  //curve is drawn from C to D
C D E A  //curve is drawn from D to E 
D E A B  //curve is drawn from E to A
E A B C  //curve is drawn from A to B
```

Initially, I went with `std::rotate`, but then realized it wasn't what I was looking for.

I'm having trouble implementing this. Best I got is a non-working version in C++ (the reason of this failing is not the question, here's a snippet).

```
static char letters = 'A';
typedef struct Point{
        float x,y,z;
        char name;

        Point(float x,float y,float z=0):name(letters++){}

}Point;
typedef std::vector<Point> lpoints;

void
rotate(lpoints& points)
{
    for (unsigned int i =0;i<5;i++){
                lpoints::iterator beg =   lista.begin() + (i%5);
                lpoints::iterator dernier=lista.begin()+(4+i)%6; 

                lpoints subseq(beg,dernier); //4 points in subseq

                //do stuff with subseq                                                       
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this? I know I can implement it with many nested for loops, but i'm trying to avoid that, looking for something more elegant (if the word fits).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you expecting 5 different vectors in the solution?

Comment: @bits, 5 different vectors, or one long one, could go either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What, exactly, is wrong with using `std::rotate()`?  For example,

```
std::vector<int> v(5);

std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin() + 1, v.end());
std::vector<int> firstFour(v.begin(), v.begin() + 4);
```

`firstFour` then contains the first four elements from the rotated vector.  If you use this in a loop and run it `v.size()` times, you will get the five vectors you have in the question.

Comment: Thanks, I was looping an std::rotate, but misusing it, since I was passing v.begin()+i as a second argument (i being the loop variable)

Comment: @Tom:  As a follow-up thought, if you know that you're always going to have four elements in your resulting vectors, you might consider using the `array` container (available from Boost, C++TR1, or C++0x).

Comment: What is possibly wrong is that it is probably O(n^2) (quadratic in n), where n is the length of the vector. You can just append the vector to itself (in O(n) time) and not have to even create new vectors each time (see my answer).

Answer (score 5):

If you are willing to use more space, you can first append lpoints to itself and then increment iterators while taking subseq if needed. This also caters to your '5 different vectors or one long one', as you can just work with the iterators of the doubled vector, instead of creating new ones.

Pardon me, I haven't written C++ for a while, so here is C++ like pseudo code

```
void 
rotate(lpoints& points) 
{ 
    pointsDouble = Append(points,points); // Do your own implementation
                                 // if points is A B C D E
                                 // pointsDouble is A B C D E A B C D E

    pointsDouble::iterator beg =   lista.begin(); 
    pointsDouble::iterator dernier=lista.begin()+4;  

    for (unsigned int i =0;i<5;i++){ 

        lpoints subseq(beg,dernier); //4 points in subseq 

        //do stuff with subseq

       ++beg; ++dernier;

    } 
}
```

The for loop could perhaps be written better too, in terms of begin and end(or dernier) instead of the loop variable i.

For an append you can probably use std::copy (caveat: I am rusty in C++).

```
lpoints pointsDouble(points);
std::copy(points.begin(), points.end(), std::back_inserter(pointsDouble));
```

(back_inserter suggested by Luc)

Comment: @Tom: I thought this was elegant. You seem to have ignored it completely. Oh well...

Comment: @Moron Hope you are not offended.Didn't ignore it, but can't think of the Append function right now, trying to beat a dead line and quite tired. But thanks.

Comment: @Tom: No, not offended. Just surprised that you had nothing to say about it. For append see my edit.

Comment: To append the vector to itself, you might want to use back_inserter: `std::copy(points.begin(), points.end(), std::back_inserter(pointsDouble);`. If need be, you can call `reserve` beforehand.

Comment: @Micheal: The link seems to take forever. Please feel free to edit the answer and add it. @Luc: Thanks, I have edited to do what you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

could you do something like:

```
// vector = (a,b,c,d,e);

front = vector.front();
vector.pop_front();
vector.push_back(front);
// now you have (b,c,d,e,a);
```

repeat whatever number of times.
might be inefficient in terms of memory shuffles however

Comment: This is inefficient, O(n^2), if you're using a vector. But if you're using a list then it becomes O(n), so might be good for cases where you want to avoid copying.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much what James wrote above:

```
vector <char> newv[5];

for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
{
    newv[i].insert(newv[i].begin(),v.begin(), v.begin()+4);
    std::rotate(v.begin(), v.begin()+1, v.end());
}
```

Tested and it works.

Answer (score 0):

All the above answers require mutating a container. It is possible to solve this without doing so and still use stl / boost algorithms. Appologies if the below doesn't quite compile as I haven't tested it.

```
std::vector<int> v;
v.push_back(0);
v.push_back(1);
v.push_back(2);
v.push_back(3);
v.push_back(4);

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i ++)
{
    using boost::join;
    using boost::adaptors::sliced;
    using std::ostream_iterator;
    using std::cout;
    using boost::copy;

    copy
        ( join(v | sliced(i,4), v | sliced(0, (4 + i) % 5))
        , ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ") 
        )
    }
    cout << std::endl;

}
```

The doc for boost::sliced is at

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/range/doc/html/range/reference/adaptors/reference/sliced.html#range.reference.adaptors.reference.sliced.sliced_example